# Use a newer ZTE modem with usb-modeswitch

Tags: broadband, usb-modeswitch

Recently, I bought a 3G HSDPA modem from Cell C (South Africa). it is a ZTE MF190 capable of 7.2Mbps up and 5.76Mbps down.

So anyway i noticed usb_modeswitch does not support it. The details are as follows:

before switching: 19d2:1224
after switching: 19d2:0082

So the question is how to switch this modem? which I will provide as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So how to switch the modem,

For this model, you can just eject the fake cdrom drive and the modem switches by itself.

For a terminal/script use:

if you can find another configuration file that is similar to this modem, copy that to somewhere convenient, and then edit so that it reflects the device and vendor ids for this modem. then try switching using

`usb_modeswitch -c "path to config file"`

With this model, the settings for the vodafone K380* modems works. The settings are in the files 19d2:1013 or 19d2:0013 in the /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/ folder for ubuntu lucid.
So just get those files, update with the details you find from `lsusb` for this modem and then you should be ok!

Comment: Eshwar you should mark this as answered if this works

Comment: thanks, the latest `usb-modeswitch' does this automatically though! No need of my solution anymore!

Comment: What should be in the config file?

Answer (score 0):

Better to disable the load as a CDROM, I did the same with my PROLINK PHS600 (Vendor=19d2 ProdID=1253) which is now recognized as **ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM**

Do it using your desktop, then no need to install usb_modeswitch (which is btw replaced by usbmode in openwrt trunk, I write it after spending hours looking for it ..)

> ZTE AT-commands
>
> This is a featured page disable/enable flash cd-drive
>
> AT+ZCDRUN=8 disable
>
> AT+ZCDRUN=9 enable

source: http://www.3g-modem-wiki.com/page/ZTE+AT-commands