# How do I make ZTE MF192 USB modem work?

Tags: usb, modem, broadband, zte, usb-modeswitch

The closest to a solution is: 
[Getting a Huawei EC159 USB Modem working on Ubuntu 11.04](http://sajjad.in/2011/10/getting-an-huawei-ec159-usb-modem-working-on-ubuntu-11-04/)

I have no idea what flag to pass to `usb_modeswitch` and I do not want to mess up anything. The output from `lsusb`:

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 19d2:0146 ONDA Communication S.p.A.

Is ZTE MF192 supported at all?

---

See also

- https://askubuntu.com/q/101193/23468
- [Use a newer ZTE modem with usb-modeswitch](https://askubuntu.com/q/31477/23468)
- [ZTE USB Modem - Make it work](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1932350)
- [Mobile Broadband ZTE MF192 Stick under Linux](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1877737)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer was found on the [USB ModeSwitch forum](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/bb/viewtopic.php?t=889).